# How to set up openshift document in Docker container?

Tags: docker, nginx, openshift, dockerfile, openshift-origin

I'm so confuse that Openshift offer a way to set up document workstation locally with ascii_binder, that's ok, i can do it. but there is question, i want to set up [openshift-docs](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-docs) in docker container, any way i have tried is useless.

Here is my idea:

I use `asciibinder build` in openshift-docs and generated _preview directory

After that, I made a image base on nginx and copy all files include _preview directory in to image's directory `/usr/share/nginx/html`.

After image generated, i use docker run to setup a container.

I entered in the container, changed the default.conf in `/etc/nginx/conf.d`, made the root become `/usr/share/nginx/html/_preview/openshift-origin/latest`.

After that, i restart container and entered it again.

Changed current directory to `/usr/share/nginx/html` , and use command `asciibinder watch`.

But when i view it in browser, there are many sources like js and css not found.

**is my idea right? if it's wrong, so How can i set up openshift-docs in docker container?**

my Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.13.0
MAINTAINER heshengbang "trulyheshengbang@gmail.com"
ENV REFRESHED_AT 2018-04-06

RUN apt-get -qq update
RUN apt-get -qq install vim
RUN apt-get -qq install ruby ruby-dev build-essential nodejs git
RUN gem install ascii_binder


COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html/


CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

- https://github.com/openshift-s2i/s2i-asciibinder

They even supply an example of deploying:

- https://github.com/openshift/openshift-docs.git

The `README` only shows `s2i` command line usage to build a docker image and run it, but to deploy in OpenShift you can run:

```
oc new-app openshift/asciibinder-018-centos7~https://github.com/openshift/openshift-docs.git
oc expose svc openshift-docs
```

Comment: I did it follow [s2i-asciibinder](https://github.com/openshift-s2i/s2i-asciibinder), but here is a error: `sed: can't read .git/config: No such file or directory
Build failed
ERROR: An error occurred: non-zero (13) exit code from openshift/asciibinder-018-centos7
` . I checked it in https://github.com/openshift/openshift-docs/blob/master/.s2i/bin/assemble, that's where error occured, I don't much sure the error is mine or openshift-docs.

Comment: For whatever reason, it may not work now when pointed at a remote Git repository. You may have to checkout the Git repository locally and run ``s2i`` as ``s2i build --copy . openshift/asciibinder-018-centos7 openshift-docs``.

Comment: Also, checkout "How to deploy to OpenShift" https://github.com/openshift/openshift-docs/blob/master/contributing_to_docs/tools_and_setup.adoc#next-steps

Comment: I tried it locally, but failed. the error log is same like remote. I have added a issue to [openshift-docs](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-docs).

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy an asciibinder website on OpenShift with the following template: https://github.com/openshift/openshift-docs/blob/master/asciibinder-template.yml.

You can import this with

```
oc create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openshift/openshift-docs/master/asciibinder-template.yml
```

Then deploy from the web console via
[image]

Make sure you have an `assemble` script similar to https://github.com/openshift/openshift-docs/blob/master/.s2i/bin/assemble in your project.

Comment: The way you mentioned above I have tried. But useless. [assemble](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-docs/blob/master/.s2i/bin/assemble) have error when i use `s2i build`, so as oc. I have found another way to deploy openshift-docs in offline environment. I create a repository in [github](https://github.com/heshengbang/deployLocalDoc) to help people who wanna to do like me.